# Multiple checkbox database insert with mysql prepare

Tags: php, mysql

I have checkboxes generated with this code:

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo "<input type='checkbox' name='branch[]' value='".$row['id']."'> ".$row['name']."<br>";
}
```

And I need to insert value of every checkbox in mysql database. Code that I have inserts it for every checkbox but only `$member_id`, `$branch` is always inserted as 0. What am I doing wrong?

```
$sql = "SELECT id FROM members WHERE email='$email'";
$result = mysqli_query($mysqli,$sql);
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
$member_id = $row["id"];
$checked_arr = $_POST['branch'];
$branch_count = count($checked_arr);
for ($i = 0; $i < $branch_count; $i++) {
    if ($insert_stmt_branch = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO members_branch (member, branch) VALUES (?, ?)")){         
    $insert_stmt_branch->bind_param('ss', $member_id, $branch);

        if (! $insert_stmt_branch->execute()) {
            echo "ERROR: branch insert";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: check the fetched array from where you are getting the values of `$member_id` and `$branch`. `var_dump($row)`

Comment: `$branch` in `$insert_stmt_branch->bind_param('ss', $member_id, $branch);` does not exist. You want to use `$checked_arr[$i]` -> `$insert_stmt_branch->bind_param('ss', $member_id, $checked_arr[$i]);`

Comment: You probably should `prepare` your SQL *outside* the loop, so you can reuse it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the start of your for loop, you forgot to add:

```
$branch = $checked_arr[$i];
```

Also, you don't have anything to verify that your query looking up by email address returns a value. If no account is found, your $member_id value will be blank.

Answer (score 1):

You never assign a value to `$branch`